# Nodemailer SES TRANSPORT Error: "UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Destination' found in params"

Tags: amazon-ses, nodemailer

Facing issue while sending AWS SES Templated email using SES TRANSPORT from Nodemailer.

In [SES TRANSPORT Documentation](https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/), it says

```
To use SES transport, set a aws.SES object as the value for SES property in Nodemailer transport options.
```

Here's how my code looks.

```
transporter.sendMail({
  ses: { 
          Destination: {
          CcAddresses: [], 
          ToAddresses: 'recipient@example.com'
        },
        Source: 'sender@example.com' ,
        Template: 'template_name' ,
        TemplateData: JSON.stringify(data) ,
        // optional extra arguments for SendRawEmail
        Tags: [{
            Name: 'tag name',
            Value: 'tag value'
        }]
  }
}, (err, info) => {
    console.log(info.envelope);
    console.log(info.messageId);
});
```

This is the error I am getting.

```
2019-08-12T17:03:38.210Z error: There were 3 validation errors:
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Destination' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Template' found in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'TemplateData' found in params
```